# Get String from a single cell in Ucanaccess (Java)

Tags: java, ucanaccess

I'm using Ucanaccess for a highschool project, and I need to get a String from a single cell in Access. I have investigated, but the only option that seems to be available is to use `connection.getString(int)`, but that only gets the whole row.

Comment: Access is a database platform so what is it exactly that you are trying to acquire? A specific string from a column in a specific record row? You'll need a SELECT query for that. Or is it the string content form a filled JTable (with data from an Access Database) row/column cell?

Comment: A specific string from a column in a specific record row, that's what I need, can you give an example from the SELECT query?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to download and include the **ucanaccess** and other accompanying jar files to your Java Project [here's how you can do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zb1AWUroicM).

Now let's say you have an MS Access database named **UserLoginDB.accdb** which (for simplicity) contains a single data table named **UsersTable** which consists of 3 specific columns named, **ID** (AutoNumber), **LoginName** (Text), and **Password** (Text). Add some fictitious data into this MS Access DB table so that this db data can be retrieved from your Java Application. Make sure one of the records in your Users Table contains this data (for demo purposes):

```
       LoginName:    Fred Flintstone
       Password:     123456
```

Close your MS Access database.

Now, given the password string of **"123456"** we're going to access the MS Access Database named **UserLoginDB.accdb** and acquire the owner (LoginName) of that password contained within the UserTable. Somewhere in your Java application (a button event or whatever) paste the following code:

```
String nl = System.lineSeparator();
String dbPath = "";
            
// Navigate and select the MS Access database file:
javax.swing.JFileChooser fileChooser = new javax.swing.JFileChooser(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter filter = 
                new javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter("MS Access Database", 
                "mdb", "mde", "accdb", "accde", "accdw");
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this); //(Component) evt.getSource());
if (returnVal == javax.swing.JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(nl + "File Selection Error!" + nl
                + "The Database file can not be found at the supplied path:" + nl
                + "(" + file.toString() + ")." + nl);
    }
    String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
    if (!ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".mdb") && !ext.equalsIgnoreCase(".accdb")
            && !ext.equals(".accdw") && !ext.equals(".accde") && !ext.equals(".mde")) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(nl + "File Selection Error!" + nl
                + "The Database file selected is not a Microsoft Access Database file: "
                + "(" + file.getName() + ")." + nl);
    }

    try {
        dbPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
    
String userName = "";
String password = "";
String dbURL = "";
java.sql.Connection conn = null;
try {
    dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbPath + ";memory=false";
    conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, userName, password); 
    String sql = "SELECT LoginName FROM "
            + "UsersTable WHERE Password = ?;";
    try (java.sql.PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1, "123456");
            
        try (java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("LoginName"));
            }
        }
    }
    conn.close();
}
catch (java.sql.SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

The above code allows you to navigate your local file system so that you can find where you created your **UserLoginDB.accdb** database file and select it. Once the file dialog's <kbd>Open</kbd> button is selected then MS Access Database will accessed and the UsersTable queried for the Password **123456** and the name **Fred FlintStone** (related to this password) will be printed into the Console Window.